Software to transfer files from camscanner on android to PC?
I am writing my notes by hand in paper and scanning them using camscanner to put into my obsidian vault. While, I am aware obsidian sync exists, I don't find it affordable for me to use it and I don't trust my skills to make free syncing options work correctly.
I tried telegram but it is compressing my images.
I can't use viber as it's used for office purposes. And I can't afford to mistakenly send files to a different group.
Whatsapp doesn't have save notes facility(at least I don't see in mine).
Email is tedious. I want to be able to copy paste the image into obsidian(note taking app).
USB is not good because I want to transfer images after I write notes about a topic. So everyday, I will need to transfer 2 images every hour. I can't do it in bulk.
Can you suggest me an easy way to transfer files using bluetooth or wifi which I can either just drag and drop into obsidian or copy paste into obsidian?

Hi. I would suggest you look at the free sync for obsidian again. The alternative is to try opensource https://syncthing.net/

I write images based notes and they'll probably go beyond 20GB in near future. What is best for my case? @ZZ
